# (F,G) is an adjoint pair iff there are morphisms of functors $\epsilon: id_C \to G \circ F, \eta: F \circ G \to id_D$ with commutative diagrams

Tags: category-theory

We are discussing category theory now. We got the following exercise in class. $F: \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$, $G: \mathcal{D} \to \mathcal{C}$. Show that $(F,G)$ is an adjoint pair if and only if there are morphisms of functors $\epsilon: id_C \to G \circ F, \eta: F \circ G \to id_D$ such that the following diagrams commute

1. $\forall Y \in \mathcal{D}: G(\eta(Y)) \circ \epsilon(G(Y)) = id(G(Y)) $
2. "a similar expression from $F(X) \to F(G(F(X))) \to F(X) $"(you have to find the expressions).

I tried to prove first the direction $\implies$. Since $F, G$ are adjoint, so there exist morphisms $\epsilon: id_C \to G \circ F, \eta: F \circ G \to id_D$. We only have to proof 1) and 2) for these morphisms. So I started to proof that $G(\eta(Y)) \circ \epsilon(G(Y)) \circ f = f$, with $f: Z \to G(Y) \in Hom_\mathcal{D}(Z, G(Y))$ arbitrary, $Y \in \mathcal{C}, Z \in \mathcal{D}$ arbitrary. I denote $\epsilon(A) = \epsilon_A$.

$G(\eta_Y) \circ \epsilon_{G(Y)} \circ f = G(\eta_Y) \circ (G \circ F)(f) \circ \epsilon_Z$, in this step we used commutative diagram 1. [Commutative diagram 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwwMe.png)
This equals $G(\eta_Y \circ F(f)) \circ \epsilon_Z$. Now I am stuck.

For the other direction, I am looking for a isomorphism of the bifunctors, but I am stuck as well.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Have you looked at other questions or any resources about this? This is well known and proven in many places. It may help to clarify what *you* mean by an adjoint pair, too; there are a few equivalent ways to define adjunction.